# Failing to increase x-axis ticks with usual code

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a daily dataframe that I would like to plot:

```
xx=data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), by = "day"),
              Data = randn(length(seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), by = "day")),1),
              stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I then plot it like this:

```
ggplot(xx) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Data), col = "blue") +
  labs(y = "", x = "") + theme_classic()
```

Yet, I want to have every year on the x-axis and when I try to do it like this:

```
ggplot(xx) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Data), col = "blue") +
  labs(y = "", x = "") + theme_classic() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(xx$Date), max(xx$Date), by = "year"))
```

I get: `Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied`. I don't manage to sort this.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
#Data
xx=data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), by = "day"),
              Data = randn(length(seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), by = "day")),1),
              stringsAsFactors = F)
#Code
ggplot(xx) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Data), col = "blue") +
  labs(y = "", x = "") + theme_classic() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(min(xx$Date), max(xx$Date), by = "year"),
               date_labels = '%Y')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It's great thanks. It would be even better to have only the year displayed on the x-axis. Any idea to get it?

Comment: @Rollo99 I have updated the code for what you want. Hope that helps and let me know if it works!

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks a lot! I'll mark it as the correct one once SO allows me to do so. Thanks again :)